# how to create polo with same filed in one json string

Tags: java, json, gson

The json string is

```
{
    "TS" :{
      "name":"abc",
      "value":"123"
    },
    "DB" :{
      "TS":  {
                "MMPTELID": "043199",
                "UNIQUEID": "43199"
             }
    }
}
```

It has two same filed TS, but they are not the same key. How to create the polo object. I want to gson parse the string with class.

I have created these pojo objects

```
public class MyPojo
{
    private DB DB;

    private TS TS;

    public DB getDB ()
    {
        return DB;
    }

    public void setDB (DB DB)
    {
        this.DB = DB;
    }

    public TS getTS ()
    {
        return TS;
    }

    public void setTS (TS TS)
    {
        this.TS = TS;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return "ClassPojo [DB = "+DB+", TS = "+TS+"]";
    }
}

public class DB
{
    private TS TS;

    public TS getTS ()
    {
        return TS;
    }

    public void setTS (TS TS)
    {
        this.TS = TS;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return "ClassPojo [TS = "+TS+"]";
    }
}

public class TS
{
    private String name;

    private String value;

    public String getName ()
    {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName (String name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getValue ()
    {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue (String value)
    {
        this.value = value;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return "ClassPojo [name = "+name+", value = "+value+"]";
    }
}
```

How to handle the two TS object ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to keep the same `TS` object, just add the two other variables to it.

```
public class TS {
    // ....

    private String MMPTELID;
    private String UNIQUEID;

    // ....
}
```

Output

```
MyPojo [DB = DB [TS = TS [name=null, value=null, MMPTELID=043199, UNIQUEID=43199]], TS = TS [name=abc, value=123, MMPTELID=null, UNIQUEID=null]]
```

The issue here will be that in one case your object will have `name` and `value` set and the other variables will be null, and in the other case it will be reversed.

Otherwise, you need another class.

```
public class OtherTS {
    private String MMPTELID;
    private String UNIQUEID;

    // ....
}
```

And in your `DB` class change the variable type of `TS` to `OtherTS`.

```
public class DB {
    private OtherTS TS;

    // ....
}
```

Output

```
MyPojo [DB = DB [TS = TS [MMPTELID=043199, UNIQUEID=43199]], TS = TS [name=abc, value=123]]
```

Comment: Thanks you .I created another class OtherTS . It worked.